# Rolling window lookback counts for feature engineering

Tags: pandas

I am trying to add new features to my ML model in hopes of improving recall. Basically, I'm dealing with sales data and the relevant  columns are - transaction time stamp, unique customer id and sales channel. All I want is to add new engineered features that a simple counts of past store visits in 7days, 30days etc.

So if the base data looks like this:

| Timestamp | Cust_id | Channel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3/5/2024 | C1 | instore |
| 3/5/2024 | C1 | instore |
| 2/27/2024 | C1 | cc |
| 2/19/2024 | C1 | instore |
| 11/26/2023 | C1 | web |
| 3/5/2024 | C2 | cc |
| 2/29/2024 | C2 | instore |
| 2/24/2024 | C2 | instore |
| 1/25/2024 | C2 | cc |

to something like this

| Timestamp | Cust_id | Channel | instore_7d_visits | cc_7d_visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/5/2024 | C1 | instore | 1 | 1 |
| 3/5/2024 | C1 | instore | 0 | 1 |
| 2/27/2024 | C1 | cc | 0 | 0 |
| 2/19/2024 | C1 | instore | 0 | 0 |
| 11/26/2023 | C1 | web | 0 | 0 |
| 3/5/2024 | C2 | cc | 1 | 0 |
| 2/29/2024 | C2 | instore | 1 | 0 |
| 2/24/2024 | C2 | instore | 0 | 0 |
| 1/25/2024 | C2 | cc | 0 | 0 |

Basically I want to be able to create more lookback window based features like 30 days, 90 days, 1 year etc.

Right now I am iterating through the rows and checking for transactions but its extremely slow.
I tried window functions in SQL but the window lenght is not a static number of records so its now working for me.

Comment: Are you aware of [`DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)? User guide: [Windowing operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html)